# Convert string value to date from FormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, parsing

I get `new Date(2012,9,3)` from `FormCollection["eventDate"]`
how can I get this value in `DateTime` variable?

Comment: Just curious, why you send this kind of string `new Date(2012,9,3)` instead of using DateTime format?

Comment: Please show the code, these sorts of pseudo-code questions are nearly impossible to answer well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = "new Date(2012,9,3)";

var dateTimeString = input.Split(new[] {'(', ')'}, 
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                          .Last();

var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, 
                                   "yyyy,M,d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This line `input.Substring(input.IndexOf('(') + 1, 8);` would fail if there were a month or day with two digits. The length would need to be longer than 8.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: you are right, I am on the way to correct it

Comment: This works for me, 
But is there any proper way to convert , rather then converting into string,

Thanks Cuong Le

Answer (score 0):

One way would be like this:

```
// new Date(2012,9,3)
var dateVals = s.Substring(9).Replace(")", "").Split(",");
var d = new DateTime(
    Convert.ToInt32(dateVals[0]),
    Convert.ToInt32(dateVals[2]),
    Convert.ToInt32(dateVals[1]));
```